# Bootstrap align text with checkbox

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to align a form but the elements are not aligning, how do you align the text in a form with the checkbox on the next line?

Here's what I see right now:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
      <div class="form-group" id="LocationOption">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label col-md-3">*Been to this location before?</label>

      <input class="form-check-input col-md-1" type="radio" name="Location_sel" id="LocationYes" value="Yes" onclick="location_select(1)">
      <label class="form-check-label col-md-2 text-center" for="LocationYes">Yes</label>

      <input class="form-check-input col-md-1" type="radio" name="Location_sel" id="LocationNo" value="No" onclick="location_select(0)">
      <label class="form-check-label col-md-2 text-center" for="LocationNo">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check col-md-9">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="TnC" value="TnC">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="TnC">
        By clicking submit, you agree to our <a class="text-primary" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Terms and Conditions</a>
      </label>
      <label class="form-check-label text-danger" id="TnCAlert"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need checkbox and label text in 2 different lines?

Comment: @Master.Deep yes 2 different lines please, just align the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="form-group" id="LocationOption">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label col-md-3">*Been to this location before?</label>

            <input class="form-check-input col-md-1" type="radio" name="Location_sel" id="LocationYes" value="Yes"
                onclick="location_select(1)">
            <label class="form-check-label col-md-2 text-center" for="LocationYes">Yes</label>

            <input class="form-check-input col-md-1" type="radio" name="Location_sel" id="LocationNo" value="No"
                onclick="location_select(0)">
            <label class="form-check-label col-md-2 text-center" for="LocationNo">No</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check col-md-9">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="TnC" value="TnC">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="TnC">
                By clicking submit, you agree to our <a class="text-primary" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#exampleModalLong">Terms and Conditions</a>
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-label text-danger" id="TnCAlert"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.form{ display:flex; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this I get everything displaying in one line, i'm looking for the "been to this location before" and the terms and conditions line on two different lines but just alligning the left

Comment: ooh you can add ```ml-3``` to the checkbox lable class like ```<label class="form-check-label ml-3" for="TnC">```